# How to download file PDF larger than 12 MB?

Tags: php

I have a problem with download file in php when download file larger than 12 MB, but success download file lower than 12 MB.
This is my code :

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST["file"])){
    $file = urldecode($_REQUEST["file"]); // Decode URL-encoded string

        if(file_exists($file)) {
        $fp = fopen($file, "rb");

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');

        header('Expires: 0');

        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header('Pragma: public');

        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

        set_time_limit(0);

        readfile($file);
        ob_end_clean();

        die(fpassthru($fp));
        fclose($fp);
        exit;
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM IS SOLVED.** Just remove a symbol character of the filename.

Comment: Do you have anything after the header declarations? After line 48? Because of the way php works, you generally don't output information after the headers have been set.

Comment: Cheers! How are you using the download Class? Can you show that code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php to see if the headers are sent before it ?

Comment: Thats all the code? There is nothing after `$download->download($file);` ? The error message would suggest that there is something being output after `$download->download($file);` is executed.

Comment: I bet if you removed `echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$link.'">';` it would work. The download class you are using is already setting the headers for the page, so you are unable to output anything after calling `$download->download($file);` (echo is a way of outputing information)

Comment: @Jeemusu, still same bro

Comment: I just tested your code locally and it worked fine. There is obviously something else going on in your application that is outputting data after `$download->download($file);` has been called. Ensure `$download->download($file);` is that last thing being called in your application.

Comment: @Jeemusu, I have been tried another code, but still can't download larger than 12 MB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194350/discussion-between-franksye-sipangkar-and-jeemusu).

Comment: Is there any particular reason for doing this when you could use <a href='mypdf.pdf' target='_blank'>my pdf file</a>

Comment: readfile function does not need fopen and fclose. The simplest code for downloading can be found at https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.readfile.php

Comment: i think you need to adjust some settings on your server.